# How does the methods "shouldChangeTextInRange" and "stringByReplacingCharactersInRange" work?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, textfield

I would like to know the working of the following code.

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    return !([newString length] > 10);
}
```

What does "stringByReplacingCharactersInRange" do? And how does the above method limit the number of characters that can be entered in the textField?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) method that gets called any time text field's contents are about to change (entering, deleting, cutting or pasting text into the text field), asking the delegate if it wants to allow this change.

`stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:` is an NSString instance method that does exactly what it says, replaces some text in current string with another string, creating a new string.

The code you have checks if the string that would be a result of this change is longer than 10 characters and if it is, delegate will return `NO` and text field contents will not change. If the resulting string would be 10 characters or less, delegate will return `YES` and text field's contents will change to the same string that you got in `newString`.

Comment: Thank you! But what would be the value of 'range' in the above code??

Comment: An `NSRange` structure containing index of starting character and length of the part of string that will be replaced. If user is entering text, range.location will be index of last character + 1, and range.length will be 1. If user is deleting selected text, range.location will be index of first selected character, and range.length will be number of characters that are selected.

Comment: okay.. suppose if the textField is empty, and the user is entering text, then "range" will have the length of characters the user enters?

Comment: *Every* time text field is about to change, this delegate method will get called with new range. When entering characters into empty text field, it will get called with range 0,1 for 1st char, 1,1 for second, 2,1 for third and so on.

Comment: Fichek, just to clarify, does the 0,1 value for range indicate that the index is 0 and length of the string to be replaced is 1??

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: `shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementString:` is not a `UITextFieldDelegate` method, it's a `UITextInput` protocol optional method. `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` is the `UITextFieldDelegate` method. Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Answerbot yeah, missed the first part of selector when copy/pasting, thanks for spotting it.