# How to not allow typing 'space' in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uitextview

I have a UITextView and I do not want the user to have any spaces in the text typed. What should I do to not allow him to use the space button?
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554340/how-does-the-methods-shouldchangetextinrange-and-stringbyreplacingcharactersi     Just dont allow spaces aka @" " with the method seen in the link. Remember to set the delegate of the text view

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to

1. Specify the view controller as the `delegate` to your text view (you can do this either programmatically or specify the delegate in Interface Builder); and
2. Your `UITextViewDelegate` method `shouldChangeTextInRange` needs to check to see if the string to be inserted *contains* a space:

   ```
   - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
       if ([text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
           return NO;
       }
       return YES;
   }
   ```

   Or, in Swift:

   ```
   extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
       func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
           return text.rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == nil
       }
   }
   ```

   Note, this is not checking to see if the `replacementText` is equal to space, because that is an insufficient check. Instead, this is checking whether a space occurs *anywhere* inside the replacement text. This is an important distinction because it's possible to paste text into the text view that might not be equal to a space, but might contain a space somewhere in the pasted value.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to do this is by preventing the edit in the first place:

In your ViewController.h file, make it implement the UITextViewDelegate protocol:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

In your ViewController's viewDidLoad method in the ViewController.m, set the textField's delegate to the view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.myTextView.delegate = self;
}
```

Finally, we need to capture the changes as they happen and remove the spaces.  We can do this in the textViewDidChange: method. Returning NO in the shouldChangeTextInRange: method when there are spaces in the new string will prevent the user from pasting text that has spaces in them (may not be what you want). If we simply remove the spaces, the user cannot type a new space from the keyboard, but if they were to do a paste with something like "hello world" in the clipboard, they would get "helloworld" in the TextView:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // eliminates spaces, including those introduced by autocorrect
    if ([textView.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound) {
        textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[How does the methods "shouldChangeTextInRange" and "stringByReplacingCharactersInRange" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554340/how-does-the-methods-shouldchangetextinrange-and-stringbyreplacingcharactersi)

Just dont allow spaces aka @" " with the method seen in the link(

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
 if( [string isEqualToString:@" "] )
    return NO;
 else 
    return YES;
}
```

Remember to set the delegate of the text view