# UITextview delegate method shouldChangeTextInRange not detecting space character in Objective C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

UITextview delegate method shouldChangeTextInRange will detect a single space character only after multiple attempts from UIKeyboard.All other keys from UIKeyboard become disabled state while tapping space bar in UIKeyboard.

Do you have any idea about this issue?

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{ 

if([textView.text isEqualToString:@“sometext”]){ 

textView.text = @""; 
self.myTextview.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0/255.0 green:92.0/255.0 blue:111.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]; 
} 
return true;
```

Comment: I think it would help if you add your code in `shouldChangeTextInRange`

Comment: - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

    if([textView.text isEqualToString:@“sometext”]){

        textView.text = @"";
        self.myTextview.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0/255.0 green:92.0/255.0 blue:111.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }

    return true;
}

Comment: please update your question with this code formatted properly: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @ShawnFrank I have formatted the code snippet

Comment: What is the end goal you want ? From the code it seems you want check if a specific text was entered and if that text was entered you clear the textView. I am not so sure of what your objective is. Could you clarify that ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank Whatever logic which I have put in shouldChangeTextInRange delegate method is correct. The only problem which I am facing now is sometimes space character(" ") won't get in "replacementText" parameter when tapping on spacebar from UIKeyboard. After multiple attempts, a single space character will get from "replacementText" parameter. I hope you are clear with my points.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the method shouldChangeTextInRange. It was explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7554421/11129572). The code should be something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
NSString *newString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
if([newString isEqualToString:@"sometext"]) {
    textView.text = @"";
    textView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0/255.0 green:92.0/255.0 blue:111.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}